# Android Studio not finding unused resources

Tags: android, android-lint, android-studio-3.4

I have tried the methods explained on SO to remove unused strings, such as "Analyze...Run Inspection By Name...Unused Resources" and "Refactor....Remove Unused Resources" but the large majority of strings are not found.

I search for these strings using "Find in path" and grep, and the only places references to these strings are found are in my multiple `strings.xml` files, one entry for each of the eight translations my app has.

I have dozens of unused strings and removing them manually would be much work, is there anything to try to make lint able to recognize the strings as unused?

Comment: @a_local_nobody strings.xml

Comment: @a_local_nobody In a word, no, but I'll try more later.